# Cut a string into an array based on two words in Bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, parsing

I am currently working on a bash shell script and have a string that goes something like this:

```
"IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa"
```

I am trying to break up the string into two arrays, one with the first half and the other with the second half. In this case, the ideal array will have two elements,

```
[IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd] [IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa]
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to do this? I have tried looking online but there weren't any questions too similar to this idea.

Comment: So by "two arrays", you meant to say, "an array of two elements"? Because if each half was split by words into an array, it would have more than two elements, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
#!/bin/bash

c="IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa"

a=( IP${c##* IP} ) # ${c##* IP} remove everything up to 'IP' from left
b=( ${c% IP*} )    # ${c% IP*}  remove everything to first 'IP' from right

echo "a: ${a[@]}"
echo "b: ${b[@]}"
```

**Output**

```
$ splitscript.sh
a: IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa
b: IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd
```

**Note:** within parameter expansion braces (e.g. `${c##* IP}`) the space `' '` need not be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Bash Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
s="IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa"
pat="(IP ADDRESS:.*)(IP ADDRESS:.*)"
[[ $s =~ $pat ]] && declare -a arr=("${BASH_REMATCH[@]:1:2}")
echo "First: ${arr[0]} Second: ${arr[1]}"
```

Output:

```
First: IP ADDRESS: 12313 isjdfisafjaslfsjfasd  Second: IP ADDRESS: 21311 asdfafa
```